# Exception handling in reader of spring batch spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am using reader to read the data from db table in spring batch.

I want to handle the `JdbcSQLException` if the table is not present and log the error. I am trying to catch the exception in reader, but I'm unable to catch the exception. Where should I catch it?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [JobExecutionDecider](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/job/flow/JobExecutionDecider.html) to check for table presence.
If table is absent log error and move to job end else continue job normally.

Comment: Can I catch the exception in job launcher and log it?

Comment: You can try, but if you want a clear job flow my solution is more easy and straightforward

Answer (score 0):

You can declare an `ItemReadListener` on your reader :

```
<batch:step>
    <batch:tasklet>
        <batch:chunk reader="reader" writer="writer" />
        <batch:listeners merge="true">
            <batch:listener>
                <bean class="xx.xx.xx.YourListener"/>
            </batch:listener>
        </batch:listeners>
    </batch:tasklet>    
</batch:step>
```

In this listener, you have 3 methods at your disposal :

```
public class YourListener<T> implements ItemReadListener<T> {

    @Override
    public void beforeRead() {}

    @Override
    public void afterRead(T item) {}

    @Override
    public void onReadError(Exception ex) {}

}
```

Now for your case, you need to check the exception type in the method `onReadError` :

```
@Override
public void onReadError(Exception ex) {

     if (ex instanceof JdbcSQLException) {
         // Do your thing
     }
}
```